# Ajax AutoComplete ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know if any one know how to make an auto complete textbox that works like google chrome.
I mean that when you type "Yah" -abbreviation for Yahoo- in the address bar of google chrome 
it completes the word of Yahoo and when you click enter button it takes you to yahoo site 
all of that by type "Yah" word in address bar or make click mouse event any where in the UI
or by click enter button.
[image: Like the following picture]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the nice article

[AutoComplete TextBox With WCF](http://techarticle4u.blogspot.in/2013/08/autocomplete-textbox-with-wcf.html)

Comment: thanks for your responce, but what i mean is exactly as the post above

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jQuery and autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) or if you're using web forms with the AjaxControlToolkit look at the [autocomplete control.](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what i mean is exactly as the post above.

Comment: What technology are you using? If it's MVC this has an example: http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-in-mvc.html

Comment: No i use ASP.NET C# Web forms not MVC.

Comment: Ok, the AjaxControlToolkit has code examples in the link I sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Autocomplete For the purpose. You can customize its source to get the data from server using ajax and the binding of response. 
see AutoCompleteImplemetation in  http://www.basiccodeexample.blogspot.in/